# qunit is not returning ajax result from a javascript function with titaniuam

Tags: javascript, jquery, titanium, qunit

i careate a function in javascript in titanium.

```
function getdetail(Success){
alert("hit the function");
var detail[];
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "Detail.xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {
alert(xml);
detail.push(xml);//fill data by finding root each
sucess(detail);
}
});
return detail;
}
```

by qunit test i want to test this ,

```
test("test for detail",function(){
stop();
getdetail(function(detail){
start();
ok(true);
})

})
```

But some how it give me undefined value, null value, because i placed a alert inside the ajax function. this alert was not hit. then i place a alert outside the ajax function this was hit.

whole work i am doing with apslator titanium developer using aptana studio. 
how can i test this javascript titanium function function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I would do is install [Titanium Studio](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/download/) either on top of Aptana or standalone and then start using the [Ti.API](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.API-module).* for you're debugging instead of `alerts`. Also what exactly are you trying to accomplish. I can't tell from you're question what you are trying to do fully?